# Spark streaming performance issue. Every minute process time increasing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We are facing performance issue in my streaming application. I am reading my data from kafka topic using DirectStream and converting the data into dataframe. After doing some aggregation operation in dataframe ,I am saving the result into registerTempTable. The registerTempTable will be used for next minute dataframe compression. And compared result will be saved in HDFS and data will be overwritten in existing registerTempTable.

In this I am facing performance issue. My streaming job ruining in first min 15sec, second min 18 sec and third min 20 sec like that it keeps increasing the processing time. Over period my streaming job will queued.

About my application.

Streaming will run on every 60 sec.
Spark version 2.1.1( I am using pyspark)
Kafka topic have four partitions.

To solve the issue, I have tried below steps.
Step 1: While submitting my job I am giving “spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4” .
Step 2: while saving my dataframe as textfile I am using coalesce(4).

When I see my spark url every min run, save as file stage is doubling up like first min 14 stages, second min 28 stages and third min 42 stages.

Spark UI Result.
[image]

Hi,

Thanks for reply,

Sorry, i am new to spark. I am not sure what exactly I need change, can you please help me. do I need do unpersist my "df_data"?
I cache and unpersist my "df_data" data frame also. But still, i am facing the same issue.

Do I need to enable my checkpoint? like adding "ssc.checkpoint("/user/test/checkpoint")" this code.createDirectStream will support checkpoint? Or i need to enable offset value? please let me know what change is required here.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSqlNetworkWordCount")
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    sparkSql = SQLContext(sc)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
    zkQuorum = {"metadata.broker.list" : "m2.hdp.com:9092"}
    topic = ["kpitmumbai"]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,topic,zkQuorum)
    schema = StructType([StructField('A', StringType(), True), StructField('B', LongType(), True), StructField('C', DoubleType(), True), StructField('D', LongType(), True)])
    first_empty_df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
    first_empty_df.registerTempTable("streaming_tbl")
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x :x[1])
    lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: empty_rdd() if rdd.count() == 0 else 
    CSV(rdd))
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

def CSV(rdd1):

    spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd1.context.getConf())
    psv_data =  rdd1.map(lambda l: l.strip("\s").split("|") )
    data_1 =  psv_data.map(lambda l : Row(
            A=l[0],
            B=l[1],
            C=l[2],
            D=l[3])
    hasattr(data_1 ,"toDF")
    df_2= data_1.toDF()
    df_last_min_data = sqlCtx.sql("select A,B,C,D,sample from streaming_tbl")#first time will be empty and next min onwards have values
    df_data = df_2.groupby(['A','B']).agg(func.sum('C').alias('C'),func.sum('D').alias('D'))
    df_data.registerTempTable("streaming_tbl")
    con=(df_data.A==df_last_min_data.A) & (df_data.B==df_last_min_data.B)
    path1=path="/user/test/str" + str(Starttime).replace(" ","").replace("-","").replace(":","")
    df_last_min_data.join(df_data,con,"inner").select(df_last_min_data.A,df_last_min_data.b,df_data.C,df_data.D).write.csv(path=path1,mode="append")
```

Once again thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

> After doing some aggregation operation in dataframe ,I am saving the result into registerTempTable. The registerTempTable will be used for next minute dataframe compression. And compared result will be saved in HDFS and data will be overwritten in existing registerTempTable.

The most likely problem is you don't checkpoint the table and lineage keeps growing with each iteration. This makes each iteration more and more expensive, especially when data is not cached.

Overall if you need stateful operations you should prefer existing stateful transformations. Both "old" streaming and structured streaming come with their own variants, which can be used in a variety of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Above I have added my code for your reference. can you please help where I need change.